# how to set table row colors depending on label "yes/no" clicks per row

Tags: angularjs

I have been attempting to get the following piece of code to work but have as yet no been able to find a good solution. I have succesfully done this type of functionality via jQuery but my new requirements are to figure out how to do it in an angular way.

I have a table which is contructed via ng-repeat, each row contains a set of yes/no buttons in order to "approve" or "decline" the data visible in each row. When a row is either approved or declined, the color of that row will change to either green or red.

Currently all my rows are changing colors instead of only the row where Yes/No was clicked. I have tried doing something with the index and sending through the id (term in this case) and countless other things but I am unsure what to do inside the controller and how to add the class name specific to each row. Help would be greatly appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="tableData in maximumOfferData" ng-class="{0:'test-none', 1:'test-yes',2:'test-no'}[classstatusmaximum]">
                  <td>{{tableData.term}}</td>
                  <td>{{tableData.offer}}</td>
                  <td>{{tableData.payment}}</td>
                  <td>{{tableData.coverage}}</td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                      <label  data-ng-model="testyes"
                              data-btn-radio="'Left'"
                              class="btn btn-default ok ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"
                              ng-click="changeMaximumStatusYes(tableData.term)">
                        YES
                      </label>
                      <label  data-ng-model="testyes"
                              data-btn-radio="'Middle'"
                              class="btn btn-default nok ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"
                              ng-click="changeMaximumStatusNo(tableData.term)">
                        NO
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
```

**Controller.js:**

```
 $scope.maximumOfferData= [
      {'term':'7', 'offer':'11500', 'payment':'11.57', 'coverage':'18' },
      {'term':'8', 'offer':'12500', 'payment':'16.88', 'coverage':'24' },
      {'term':'9', 'offer':'9500', 'payment':'18.72', 'coverage':'12' }
    ];

    $scope.classstatusmaximum = "0";

    $scope.changeMaximumStatusYes = function(offerid){
      console.log(offerid);
      if ($scope.classstatusmaximum !== "1")
        $scope.classstatusmaximum = "1";
    };

    $scope.changeMaximumStatusNo = function(offerid){
      console.log(offerid);
      $scope.classstatusmaximum = offerid;
      if ($scope.classstatusmaximum !== "2")
        $scope.classstatusmaximum = "2";
    };
```

See above Plunker attempt Here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/3OjtzSUWdWCYTpXqxtOd?p=preview

Comment: You need to implement `classstatusmaximum` as an array of values - one for each row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this line in the html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="tableData in maximumOfferData" 
    ng-class="{0:'test-none', 1:'test-yes',2:'test-no'}[tableData.status]">
```

and this

```
<label  data-ng-model="testyes"
                          data-btn-radio="'Left'"
                          class="btn btn-default ok ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"
                          ng-click="changeMaximumStatusYes(tableData)">
                    YES
                  </label>
                  <label  data-ng-model="testyes"
                          data-btn-radio="'Middle'"
                          class="btn btn-default nok ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"
                          ng-click="changeMaximumStatusNo(tableData)">
                    NO
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.maximumOfferData= [
  {'term':'7', 'offer':'11500', 'payment':'11.57', 'coverage':'18','status':'0' },
  {'term':'8', 'offer':'12500', 'payment':'16.88', 'coverage':'24','status':'0' },
  {'term':'9', 'offer':'9500', 'payment':'18.72', 'coverage':'12','status':'0' }
];

$scope.changeMaximumStatusYes = function(data){
  data.status = "1";
};

$scope.changeMaximumStatusNo = function(data){
  data.status = "2";
};
```

In this way you set a different status on every line, rather than set the status on a single var

Comment: You may want to provide an explanation as to why that works as well

Comment: Explanations always go the extra mile, but regardless, that is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much David, it seems so much easier that I had thought. I am new to angular and have barely used ng-class. Thank you very much for this!

Comment: I add a second change on the html

Comment: thank you once again! Exactly what I needed, that was the quickest assistance i've ever found. :) ng-class is proving quite usefull.